# TSQL query for data control in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can any TSQL expert help me with following issue:

I have a database with a table named "Data" and this table has following columns:

```
ID| RunId| AccountStaf_1 |AccountStaf_2 |AccountNr|
-------------------------------------------
```

The table will contain following data:

```
ID| RundId| AccountStaf_1 | AccountStaf_2 | AccountNr|
----------------------------------------------
1 | A |  xxx           |NULL           | 123456   |
2 | A |  yyy           |NULL           | 123456   |
3 | A |                | zzz           | 123456   |
4 | A |  fff           | NULL          | 123444   |
5 | B |  NULL          | hhh           | 666666   |
6 | B |  bbb           | NULL          | 666666   |
```

Can anyone help me to define a TSQL query to find all the accountNr which has a AccountStaf_1 and AccountStaf_2 under the same "RunId".

The outcome of the result should be this:

```
 ID| RunId| AccountStaf_1 | AccountStaf_2 | AccountNr|
----------------------------------------------
1 | A |  xxx           |NULL           | 123456   |
2 | A |  yyy           |NULL           | 123456   |
3 | A |                | zzz           | 123456   |
5 | B |  NULL          | hhh           | 666666   |
6 | B |  bbb           | NULL          | 666666   |
```

E.g if you say "Where RunId = A", the outcome of the result should be this:

```
 ID| RunId| AccountStaf_1 | AccountStaf_2 | AccountNr|
----------------------------------------------
1 | A |  xxx           |NULL           | 123456   |
2 | A |  yyy           |NULL           | 123456   |
3 | A |                | zzz           | 123456   |
```

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your desired output.

Comment: There were some mistakes so I changed the description to the desired issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to return results if there are two unique AccountStaff regardless of them being in AccountStaf_1 or AccountStaf_2 fields, then you can combine the two fields using a UNION and then count UNIQUE values.  If greater than 1 then INNER JOIN on the RunId and AccountNr fields.

```
;WITH AccountStaff AS (
    SELECT RunId, AccountStaf_1 AS AccountStaff, AccountNr 
    FROM Data
    WHERE AccountStaf_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
    SELECT RunId, AccountStaf_2 AS AccountStaff, AccountNr 
    FROM Data
    WHERE AccountStaf_2 IS NOT NULL
),
AccountList AS (
    SELECT RunID, AccountNr
    FROM AccountStaff
    GROUP BY RunID, AccountNr
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AccountStaff) > 1
)
SELECT Data.ID, Data.RunId, Data.AccountStaf_1, Data.AccountStaf_2, Data.AccountNr
FROM Data INNER JOIN AccountList 
    ON Data.RunId = AccountList.runId AND Data.AccountNr = AccountList.AccountNr
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I tried you SQl and getting the same result as Thomas, but I also want the SQl to return rows where e.g. two different AccountStaf_1 has the same AccountNr. I tried with no luck.. getting different result..

Comment: I modified the SQL to accommodate this additional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your data by RunId and AccountNr and use an aggregate to see if your columns contain any values:

```
WITH
    Accounts AS
      (
         SELECT
               RunId,
               AccountNr
            FROM
               Data
            WHERE
               RunId = 'A'
            GROUP BY
               RunId,
               AccountNr
            HAVING
               MAX(AccountStaf_1) IS NOT NULL
               AND MAX(AccountStaf_2) IS NOT NULL

      )
SELECT
      D.ID,
      D.RunId,
      D.AccountStaf_1,
      D.AccountStaf_2,
      D.AccountNr
   FROM
      Data D
      INNER JOIN Accounts A
         ON A.AccountNr = D.AccountNr
            AND A.RunId = D.RunId;
```

Comment: This SQL gives me the desired outcome... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I was wondering if this SQL also return the rows where e.g. two different AccountStaf_1 has the same AccountNr. I tried to Change the SQl with no luck..?

Answer (score 0):

It's called a self join.

```
select yourFields
from data d1 join data d2 on d1.AccountNR = d2.AccountNR
where d1.id <> d2.id
```

Comment: A join is unnecessary here

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing an answer without one.

Comment: There were some mistakes so I changed the description to the desired issue.

Comment: By using group by having ocunt(*) > 1

Comment: I tried the SQL and i'm not getting the desired outcome!